How to create a tagged value as a checkbox
Is it possible to create a tagged value that is presented as a tickbox/checkbox?
Something similar to the "Abstract" or "Active" check boxes in the requirement properties element area. The image below shows the two checkboxes that I am referring to.


No not possible.
The best alternative I've found is to create an enum tagged value with values True and False.

This then looks like this when using it


Thanks for the response. I was using it like that up to now.
What a bout single item checklists?

@Mikkie I don't know. Never tried that.
